# Condition in aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new in Mongodb and I try to learn aggregation.
My database look like this:

```
{
  _id : 1,
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  c : {
    ca: 3
    cb: 5
}
},
{
  _id : 1,
  a: 3,
  b: 4,
  c : {
    ca: 3
    cb: 7
}
}
```

Is there anyway to :
- First: find max in c
- Second: create a new object like this:

```
{
   a : [ 5, 3],
   b : [6, 4],
   c : [5, 7]
}
```

My apologies if this is a repeated question but I wasn't able to find a similar one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      c: {
        $objectToArray: "$c"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      a: {
        $push: "$a"
      },
      b: {
        $push: "$b"
      },
      c: {
        $push: {
          $max: "$c.v"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sD0Ey3mf9B4)

Comment: But what happen if there are over 10 field in c and there are about 100 field in that object. And there are 2 type in object : number and object that we need to find max value